# how to create a waveform display from audio file using J2ME

Tags: audio, java-me

I'm beginner in J2ME and want to develop a mobile music editor with waveform display embedded as my project.

Is there anyone who can help me, or give me some tutorial how to encode the audio file into waveform display?

Answer (score 0):

This will generate waveform from audio file using nAudio...

```
using NAudio.Wave;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    string strPath = Server.MapPath("audio/060.mp3");
    string SongID = "2";
    byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(strPath);
    WriteToFile(SongID,strPath, bytes);
    Response.Redirect("Main.aspx");
    }

private void WriteToFile(string SongID, string strPath, byte[] Buffer)
{
    try
    {
        int samplesPerPixel = 128;
        long startPosition = 0;
        //FileStream newFile = new FileStream(GeneralUtils.Get_SongFilePath() + "/" + strPath, FileMode.Create);
        float[] data = FloatArrayFromByteArray(Buffer);

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(1170, 200);

        int BORDER_WIDTH = 5;
        int width = bmp.Width - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);
        int height = bmp.Height - (2 * BORDER_WIDTH);

        NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader reader = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));
        NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32 channelStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(reader);

        int bytesPerSample = (reader.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample / 8) * channelStream.WaveFormat.Channels;

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {

            g.Clear(Color.White);
            Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Gray);
            int size = data.Length;

            string hexValue1 = "#009adf";
            Color colour1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hexValue1);
            pen1.Color = colour1;

            Stream wavestream = new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(strPath, wf => new NAudio.FileFormats.Mp3.DmoMp3FrameDecompressor(wf));

            wavestream.Position = 0;
            int bytesRead1;
            byte[] waveData1 = new byte[samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample];
            wavestream.Position = startPosition + (width * bytesPerSample * samplesPerPixel);

            for (float x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                short low = 0;
                short high = 0;
                bytesRead1 = wavestream.Read(waveData1, 0, samplesPerPixel * bytesPerSample);
                if (bytesRead1 == 0)
                    break;
                for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead1; n += 2)
                {
                    short sample = BitConverter.ToInt16(waveData1, n);
                    if (sample < low) low = sample;
                    if (sample > high) high = sample;
                }
                float lowPercent = ((((float)low) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float highPercent = ((((float)high) - short.MinValue) / ushort.MaxValue);
                float lowValue = height * lowPercent;
                float highValue = height * highPercent;
                g.DrawLine(pen1, x, lowValue, x, highValue);

            }
        }

        string filename = Server.MapPath("image/060.png");
        bmp.Save(filename);
        bmp.Dispose();

    }
catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
}
public float[] FloatArrayFromStream(System.IO.MemoryStream stream)
{
    return FloatArrayFromByteArray(stream.GetBuffer());
}

public float[] FloatArrayFromByteArray(byte[] input)
{
    float[] output = new float[input.Length / 4];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.Length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(input, i * 4);
    }
    return output;
}

}
```